# Is there a keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA to synchronize all Gradle projects?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Since I need to *refresh* Gradle quite often I wish to use a shortcut for this. Under

```
Settings > Keymaps
```

I just find the Gradle Tool Windows.
I use IntellJ IDEA 13.1.

Comment: Perhaps make an improvement request in the IntelliJ issue tracker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an action in the IDE to "Refresh all external projects" which should kick off a refresh for the Gradle project.

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate this action with your own keybinding. Open Settings -> Keymap and type "refresh" in the search field. Now you should see some refresh actions and the "ExternalSystem.RefreshAllProjects" as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the keymap setting, there's **Sync Project with Gradle Files**. Assign your own keymap for it.

Bringing you smoothly programming by directly using the hotkey to sync.